# Is there a workflow in Mercurial that enables many people to work on a merge (integration) together?

Tags: mercurial, merge

Say you have two “main-line” branches that have been developed separately for a long time, when you come to do the merge between them, you wish to split the work other all your developers.

E.g. you wish your C# programmer to merge the C# cope, while your TSQL programmer is merging the stored procs.

I wash all developers to be able to see what still needs to be merged and the results off each other merges, can Mercurial help with this?

[I am assuming there is more than one developer left after they have been told that they will have to do the merge!]

---

*As I have been asked in the comments, this is how I think we got into this state…*

**If I understand the history correctly** from before I joined.  One large customer came along and said “we will pay you a lot of money if you add x,y, and z to your **product**, but we are not willing to take the risk of you giving us any changes that we don’t directly benefit from (they even put some of their own programmers on the team to check they were not getting other changes).

In the few years that the work was going on for this large customer, other customers said they would not buy the product if we did not add, a, b, and c”.

The large customer was not willing to pay for x,y,and z to be done in a way (or to be able to be turned off) that did not break the product for other customers that used it in different ways, and most of the programmers that understood the system where being sold to the large customer, so there was no man power (until now) to fix x,y,and z so they could be given to all our customers.

(Basically trying to build a **product** based on **consulting** income - the fact that we were brought by a company that is closely related to the large customer in the meantime just make the politics more complex.)

At the time all this started the product did not have much automated test coverage, the code base goes back to when .net v1 shipped and all the features are well integrated both in the UI and in the source code.

Hopefully history will not repeat itself, but it is very hard for programmers to say NO in a City that does not have many software companies.   We are now moving to Mercurial, and I wish to know how we could cope with Mercurial if history did repeat itself!  (I am also starting to question if Mercurial is all it is made out to be compared to Perforce)

Comment: Probably not. Given the distributed nature of Mercurial, each repository doesn't necesseraly have knowlege of any other repository.

Comment: @JamieDixon, pushing and pulling from a central server often is not an issue, so I don't think the "distributed" nature of Mercurial will be a probem.  I am more concerned about the fact it seems not o merge/branch at the single file level.

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid [Feature Branches](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureBranch.html)

Comment: No it isn't. It's another reason not to develop two branches in isolation that will be merged later. The important part is not "two branches", rather the isolation.

Comment: @Tom, Since when have programmers had to control to stop the sales force and directors committing to two lines off development?  (With a contract saying one of them must not have any “risk” from code that the given customer does not need)

Comment: @IanRingrose, it's not worth arguing about. You believe branching is the only option. I believe there are better options. Let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sensible approach could be to use hg convert to split the repository into smaller parts (C# part, TSQL part etc), perform merges on those smaller and more fine-grained repositories, and (if keeping original repo is of importance) just commit the results back onto original repository once they are ready.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a workflow for that scenario.

Plan ahead, know before you branch which branch will merge into which later on, and make sure you merge into it regularly.

Example: You have the default branch, and create a feature branch that at some point should merge back into default. Periodically, merge from default into your feature branch to ensure it is up to date with all changes in default. This creates smaller conflicts along the way. At the end, you do one last merge into your feature branch, fix any conflicts, and then merge it into default.

This avoids "The Big Merge" at the end and creates conflicts that are easier to manage.

Comment: Avoiding "The Big Merge" is not possible when it is what the board of director’s wishes to happen!

Comment: No, on that I can agree, but then basically you're saying that the workflow that Mercurial is built to sustain is the one you've (as in your company, not necessarily you personally) chosen to drop.

Comment: @IanRingrose, genuine question (yes, I admit I was taking the piss with my first comment): what is the driver behind the director's decision? The reason I ask is that people have a natural tendency to phrase their requirements in the form of a solution. Could this be what is happening in this situation? Does the director really want a big merge or is that his solution to a real underlying requirement?

Comment: @Tom, I have aded some of the histiory to the question

Answer (score 1):

Probably the closest to what you want to achieve is to merge one change-set at a time. This avoids the big bang merge by doing lot's of little merges. If you have a clear separation between your C# devs and TSQL devs (which is sounds like you do), then you should be able to allocate each change-set to the right group.

The big negative with this approach is that you won't be able to speed up the process by doing change-sets in parallel.

The big positive with this approach is that you can test after each merge (or a small set of merges), making it easier to track down the changes that break your application. If you don't currently have a strong automated test suite, I would strongly recommend beefing it up first.

Comment: Is there a easy way to find change sets that don't depend on each other (e.g don't change a file that is change in the other change set)?   I am thinking if there will be a way to auto-devide up the work based on none overlapping changesets...

Comment: We don't have a clear separation between what our C# devs and TSQL devs do.  However our TSQL devs understand all the TSQL, but our C# devs only do the 'easy' changes to TSQL.

Comment: "The big positive with this approach is that you can test after each merge", if only our automated tests did not take about 2hr to run!  (We are starting to get faster tests that cover some of the code)

Comment: you could produce a report containing the list of files changed for each of the change-sets and consider the merge's non-overlapping if the files in the change-sets are distinct.

Comment: Also 2hrs to run your tests isn't a huge issue. In a worst case scenario, you just run then at the end of the day and in the morning your team knows if they broke anything the day before. If you keep a count of the number of times each test fails and after a week or two (I'm guess this is going to take a while) you can put the most frequently failing tests into a quick test job. The objective should be to keep the quick test job down to 10 minutes and to continue to move tests in and out of it based on failure frequencies.

Comment: that is close to what we do, but it does mean we can't merge one change list at a time, running all the tests after each merge.